# Reload Nested Fragments inside Fragment using ViewPager

Tags: android, android-activity, transactions, fragment

i have an activity with fragments and inside one fragment i nested 3 other fragments and i use viewpager to navigate between them, but when i want to change this "main fragment" which has the nested fragments i call transaction.replace and it changes the fragment but when i come back at this fragment the nested fragments are not shown again, how can i reload them everytime i launch my fragment ? 
i have tried to implement them inside my xml layout but it doesn't seems to work, i need help please !

FragmentWithViewPager:

```
public class FragmentWithViewPager extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragwithviewpager, null);

    mActionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    mActionBar.show();
    mActionBar.setTitle("MyFragment");

    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    mPager = (ViewPager) view
            .findViewById(R.id.MyFragmentMainPager);
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            tab.setIcon(tabIcon_active[tab.getPosition()]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // /tab.setIcon(null);
            tab.setIcon(tabIcon[tab.getPosition()]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tab.setIcon(tabIcon_active[tab.getPosition()]);
        }

    };
    if(mActionBar.getTabCount() < 3){
        for (int i=0; i < tabIcon.length; i++)
        {
        mActionBar.addTab(mActionBar.newTab()
                                 .setIcon(tabIcon[i])
                                 .setTabListener(tabListener));
        }
    }
    mPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentsMainPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

    new setAdapterTask().execute();

    return view;
}
rivate class setAdapterTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hide(MainFragment)
add(NewFragment)->
remove or hide(NewFragment)
show(MainFragment).

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransition().hide(MainFragment).commit().
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransition().add(R.id.containerid,MainFragment).commit().
```

Comment: The problem is that my fragments can be accessed from any other fragment i have a sliding menu with buttons where i execute transactions, how can i identify  hide(thisfragment) add (newfragment) ?

Comment: The method hide(Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int,MyFragment), it shows this ad hide method

Answer (score 0):

The Fragment that has the 3 other Fragments nested with the Viewpager should use the ChildFragmentManager.

In your activity you have your main_fragment_container in the xml that you replace or add your fragments. Correct? If true then inside the Fragment that has the Viewpager all the fragment transactions are automatically done for you if you used a FragmentPagerAdapter to accompany the Viewpager.

Then If you replace or add fragments in your main_fragment_container should not affect the contents of the Viewpager at all. When you reload the fragment with the viewpager the viewpager will reload as well if you have passed it the ChildFragmentManager.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parent, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(TextViewFragment.POSITION_KEY, position);
            return TextViewFragment.newInstance(args);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried to implement childFragmentManager at this method:  mPagerAdapter = new NotificationMainPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

but it shows that the method doesn't exist

Comment: If you use getChildFragmentManager() inside the Fragment the method does not exist? Are you using Fragment from support V4 library? P.S. You are correct this is where you should pass the ChildFragmentManager

Comment: yes i am using V4 library as with normal or v13 i cannot use viewpager inside fragment i tried ti change FragmentManager in my adapter's constructor to ChildFragmentManager but it is the same problem

Comment: Post the code of the Fragment that has the Viewpager please

Comment: notifView = view; i changed its name so it can be more easy for you to read

Comment: I don't see why if you pass getChildFragmentManager() to the PagerAdapter should be a problem. Is your adapter extending FragmentPagerAdapter?

Comment: my adapter is extending FragmentPagerAdaper , and in the Constructor  public MyFragmentsMainPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
  super(fm);
 }, i cant use ChildFragmentManager

Comment: Check the code in my edit. This should work I don't know why you say you can't pass ChildFragmentManager. I do it all the time.

Comment: i tried this method too but it still shows the same The method getChildFragmentManager() is undefined for the type NotificationsFragment